# Is there a place to link questions that show the strength of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, marketing

On this question about "[What kind of a language is JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465355/what-type-of-language-is-javascript)" there were specific answers, and that's it. That question was inviting a flame war, but none happened.

So just wondering if you have some kind of collection of questions you can suggest for new users to see the community in action with good examples of Q&A?

Comment: Errr ... the most voted answer to that question is a copy&paste from Wikipedia. Although correct, I don't think that makes a "good example" for a newbie.

Comment: True, but I suppose the OP should really have looked on Wikipedia first anyway. I was referring more to the way that it didn't explode into a flame war in the same way that it would have done on lots of other forums.

Comment: Regrettably the most voted questions in the site http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes don't reflect the current desired scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't, as far as I know.